# Sabre: "NEED WP BEFORE PQ" Error in OTA_AirPriceLLSRQ

Tags: sabre

Am getting error like "NEED WP BEFORE PQ" in the response of OTA_AirPrice, I passing SegmentSelect and trying to do booking, without SegmentSelect the request seems to process fine but if I had SegmentSelect, am not getting the response.

Have attached my request & resposnse.

**Request**

```
<OTA_AirPriceRQ ReturnHostCommand="true" Version="2.3.0" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <PriceRequestInformation Retain="true">
    <OptionalQualifiers>
       <FlightQualifiers>
          <VendorPrefs>
             <Airline Code='AI'/>
          </VendorPrefs>
       </FlightQualifiers>
       <PricingQualifiers>

           <ItineraryOptions>
              <SegmentSelect Number='0001'/>
           </ItineraryOptions>

           <PassengerType Code='ADT' Quantity='1'/> 
       </PricingQualifiers>
    </OptionalQualifiers>
 </PriceRequestInformation>
</OTA_AirPriceRQ>
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

May be unrelated, but is there any reason why you are not using the latest version of OTA_AirPrice?

Current latest version is 2.11.0 but you are showing 2.3.0...
https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/book/price_air_itinerary/resources